# Can't global uninstall npm package (eslint) OS X

Tags: npm, eslint

I have eslint installed and I wanted to update it to a newer version. Upon trying to do this, I found out that I can't get rid of my current version of eslint.

I tried uninstalling via npm but it doesn't seem to remove the command.

```
$ eslint -v
v3.0.1
$ npm uninstall -g eslint
<a huge list of eslint node_modules>
$ eslint -v
v3.0.1
```

I tried checking where the command was from and where my global packages were saved but I am not sure what to do with this information.

```
$ which eslint
/usr/local/bin/eslint
```

That file was an alias to 
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/eslint/bin/eslint.js

```
$ npm list -g
/Users/inspiredtolive/.nvm/versions/node/v7.10.0/lib
<list of packages>
```

All I really want to do is install eslint with the version greater or equal to 4.9.0. What should I do?

Comment: Is it possible you've installed it with your OS package manager as well as NPM?

Comment: @tadman Maybe. It's been over a year and a half since I first installed it so I don't remember how I installed it, but was there any other way to install it besides npm at that time? How can I check this?

Comment: Some distributions package NPM packages like that using RPM or DEB depending on your package manager. It's worth checking if they're responsible for that particular file.

Comment: Sorry. I flagged it as a possible duplicate, but gave the wrong link. I meant to suggest it is a duplicate of [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47763783](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47763783).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you have installed `eslint` globally via `yarn`. Try `yarn global remove eslint`.

BTW global yarn modules are saved here: `disk:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Yarn\Data\global\node_modules`

Answer (score 1):

You probably installed global npm package in an older node version. If this is the case reinstall all global packages to latest version directory by
running

```
nvm reinstall-packages
```

then

```
npm remove eslint
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out how my eslint was originally installed, but I ended up replacing the alias file at `/usr/local/bin/eslint` with an alias file that points to `/Users/inspiredtolive/.nvm/versions/node/v7.10.0/lib/node_modules/eslint/bin/eslint.js` and now it correctly uses the globally installed npm package.

Comment: Had the same problem. Turns out that I used `yarn` to install eslint globally.

Answer (score 0):

use from last version node for uninstall eslint.
you can use from nvm for show node installed . and switch to last version

```
npm uninstall eslint --save
```