# Uninstalling Expo CLI

Tags: create-react-app, expo

I have installed  Expo CLI globally and cant start a new react native app without using expo cli and therefore would like to uninstall it from my system. I have spent hours trying to work out how to removeit globally from my system

Answer (score 44):

To completely uninstall `expo cli`

**On Windows**

- The first step `npm -g uninstall expo-cli --save` (also `yarn global remove expo-cli`  if you use yarn).
- Second `cd %USERPROFILE% && rmdir /Q /S  .expo`

**On Mac OS Catalina**

- The first step `npm -g uninstall expo-cli --save` (also `yarn global remove expo-cli`  if you use yarn).
- Second `cd ~ && rm -rf .expo`

Thanks to @Александр Наумкин and @Liko for editing and comments

Comment: I did after uninstaling I rired create-react-native-app  it says this command reuire expo cli Why I am useing node v 13.5.0 and npm 6.13.0

Comment: try this`npx react-native init yourProjectName`

Comment: On Mac, Second: cd ~ && rm -rf .expo

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem and after searching I found this command:

```
npm -g uninstall expo-cli --save
```

finally `expo-cli` is deleted from my pc but it still asks about it every time I type create-react-native-app. if anybody knows how to go on from here be my guest.

and I hope this helps you

edit: if you use react-native init it is almost the same as create-react-native-app without `expo-cli`. This is how I chose to carry on as using the create command with `expo-cli` gives the application error after error if you install any api.

Comment: For future googlers: "expo-cli is deleted from my pc but it still asks about it everytime I type create-react-native-app" - it happens due to this method of bootstrapping has been deprecated since the CRNA project was merged with Expo.

Answer (score 10):

`npm -g uninstall expo-cli --save` did not work for me, but `yarn global remove expo-cli` did.

I expected the `npm` option to work, and was surprised when it didn't. I am using `nvm`, and wonder if this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47849940/3343716) explains why the `npm` option didn't work for me.

Answer (score 8):

if you are using npm then this command will work for uninstalling expo cli

```
npm -g uninstall expo-cli --save
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using nvm.

search for node version with expo installed.

```
find ~/.nvm -name "*expo*" -type d

nvm use {nodeversion}

npm -g uninstall expo-cli
```

Comment: Yes, new nvm users will find this answer helpful.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem once, i have tried

```
npm -g uninstall expo-cli
```

but after the my problem didn't get solved, i have searched lot even after that problem did't get solved,
i am also using yarn so finally i have decided to remove using the yarn
i tried

```
yarn global remove expo-cli
```

This indeed solved my issue

Answer (score 1):

If yarn don't work for you or you prefer using npm use:

```
npm rm -g expo cli
```

Answer (score 1):

Very simple to uninstall a npm package.
Just enter this command :

```
npm uninstall -g expo-cli
```

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 10 `npm uninstall -g expo-cli --save` worked for me from nodejs console, opening it as administrator

Answer (score 0):

In windows 10 to uninstall :

- npm uninstall -g expo-cli --save
- yarn remove global expo-cli

Worked for me.

After that, for install last version then:

- npm install -g expo-cli --save
- expo-cli --version
  3.21.13

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue.
My steps

1. npm cache clean --force
2. npx install create-react-native-app
3. cd
4. npm install -g expo-cli
5. expo start
   If you get error at 4 about node.js just install latest version. Then
6. Open your package.json file and add:

   "react-navigation": "git://github.com/Snailapp/react-navigation.git#2.18.5"
7. npm install

Answer (score 0):

Ok, in addition to existing answers, with commands like `npm -g uninstall expo-cli` and deleting manually `.expo` folder inside `%USER%` i try `expo whoami`, and my output was:

> $ expo whoami
>
> There is a new version of expo-cli available (4.13.0).
> You are currently using expo-cli 3.23.3
> Install expo-cli globally using the package manager of your choice;
> for example: `npm install -g expo-cli` to get the latest version
>
> [13:13:03] › Not logged in, run expo login to authenticate

So i had to do a bit more manual work:

- `%USER%\AppData\local` and deleted `expo` folder
- went to `%USER%\AppData\Roaming\npm` folder and manually deleted expo related files

After that i did `expo whoami` and output is:

> $ expo whoami
> bash: /c/Users/User/AppData/Roaming/npm/expo: No such file or directory

Finally, i opened new command prompt and did `npm i --g expo-cli` and after installation with `expo -V` i get `4.13.0`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows so use this command

```
npm -g uninstall expo-cli --save
```

And then run second command:

```
cd %USERPROFILE% && rmdir /Q /S  .expo
```

If the second command cannot found, open your file explorer (windows + E) and then go to disk C -> Users -> Admin, you will see .expo folder, just delete it manually.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue
i unistalled using
npm uninstall expo-cli
or
npm unistall -g expo-cli

Comment: Looks more of a comment