# "Error: Cannot find module 'metro-core'" when starting an Expo project

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm, expo, metro-bundler

Whenever I start [Expo Go](https://docs.expo.dev/get-started/expo-go) with the `expo start` command, this error appears :

```
Error: Cannot find module 'metro-core'
Require stack:
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo/node_modules/@expo/cli/build/src/start/server/metro/instantiateMetro.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo/node_modules/@expo/cli/build/src/start/server/metro/MetroBundlerDevServer.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo/node_modules/@expo/cli/build/src/start/server/DevServerManager.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo/node_modules/@expo/cli/build/src/start/startAsync.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo/node_modules/@expo/cli/build/src/start/index.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo/node_modules/@expo/cli/build/bin/cli
```

I have tried to reinstall metro-core, but with no effect.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

you are running expo start, try run

```
npx expo start
```

This should work.
Let me know if this works.

Comment: Yes, it works. But I had other troubles because the connection was LAN, so it didn't work when I tried it. Thanks so much.

Comment: I saw this issue because I just didn't include the "start":  `npx expo@latest --dev-client` 
 It'll appear to like this command and do something, but it should say something to the effect of 'invalid command'.

Comment: i have the same issue and im using npx expo start

Answer (score 5):

I had uninstalled React Native and installed it again. Then, it worked!

Also, there were some network issues when I scan the QR code using expo go app. The solution was to change the connection from LAN to tunnel using `expo start --tunnel` command.

Comment: Surprisingly, this worked for me as well.

Answer (score 2):

1. Delete the file `package-lock.json` *and* the (BIG!) directory `node_modules`.
2. Run `npm install`. (This may take a while, up to a few minutes.)
3. Finally, run `npm start` and see if the error is gone. <sup>1</sup>

##### Note!

1. The fact that you run `expo start` instead of `npx expo start` indicates that you haven't installed the Expo project *locally*.
   The official way to install Expo *used to be* `npm install -g expo-cli`.
   At the time of writing, [the official way](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup) is instead a *local* installation : 
   `npx create-expo-app Your-project-name`. 
   Then change directory to your project, `cd Your-project-name`. 
   (Running `npm install` at this point is a good idea.) 
   Finally, run `npm start` to start your Expo project. 
   *Do not install the [`expo`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/expo) package globally.* <sup>2</sup>
2. Here is a screenshot of the error `Cannot find module 'metro-core' …`

[image: Error: Cannot find module 'metro-core']

3. The [`react-native`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native) package depends directly on [`metro-runtime`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/metro-runtime).
   My best guess is that there is some intricate bug in one or both of those packages – or in some package that they depend on.
   Very hard to tell. Very hard to reproduce, as this happens intermittently.

---

<sup>1</sup>
Whether you run `npm start` – or [`npx expo start`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73536431) – or [`npm run start`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75836221) should not make any difference at all.

<sup>2</sup>
To uninstall, run `npm -g uninstall expo-cli` (or [`yarn global remove expo-cli`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58072818)).

Answer (score 1):

I am on Linux machine. `expo start` gives the same error. Instead

```
 npm run start
```

works without issue

Answer (score 0):

I kind of encountered this problem right now, and the reason it occured was running  `npm audit fix --force`
Which was leaving a danger message of vulnerability. I had to reinstall react-native to

Answer (score 0):

Install the metro packages globally with:
`npm i -g metro metro-core`

Answer (score 0):

I came to this post because I have been using `pnpm` to install the packages and `pnpm dlx` to execute, the problem is resolved once I gave up and used `npm` instead.