# Vue Cli 3 updating Issue

Tags: macos, vue.js, vue-cli-3

Terminal

[image: Terminal]

When I go to remove the cli from the global packages it doesn't seem to work in the way expected. When I go to update the cli it works, but when I try and create a new project it asks me to install it again. When I check the version I have it tells me I already have a later version than what I tried to install. I have tried a couple different ways to get it to remove the old package but have received nothing but more headaches. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using `nvm` to manage Node versions? If so, [does this help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47849940/283366)?

Comment: I will look into it currently not using nvm.

Comment: I found the issue i was using a old version of node. You got me thinking and it led me to the answer thank you!