# How Can I Uninstall browser-sync

Tags: npm, browser-sync

I tried uninstalling browser-sync and it simply won't work.

I've tried multiple times and already looked at these questions:

- [Can't uninstall global npm packages after installing nvm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47763783/cant-uninstall-global-npm-packages-after-installing-nvm)
- [How to uninstall npm modules in node js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13066532/how-to-uninstall-npm-modules-in-node-js)

I tried adding -g and it just says it's "up to date"...

```
>npm uninstall browser-sync
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE
npm ERR! file C:\Users\justi\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\triangle-calc\package.json
npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse json
npm ERR! JSON.parse Unexpected token } in JSON at position 316 while parsing near '...les.css --watch",
npm ERR! JSON.parse   },
npm ERR! JSON.parse   "keywords": [],...'
npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse package.json data.
npm ERR! JSON.parse package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\justi\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-12-28T01_44_57_830Z-debug.log

>npm uninstall browser-sync -g
up to date in 0.063s
```

I haven't had this problem uninstalling anything else before. I'm hoping posting here someone will quickly find my stupid mistake. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There was an error in my `package.json` (admittedly as the output says). It was an extra comma (apparently that works in JS but not JSON). Leaving this up in case it helps someone else trying to uninstall a package.